# wxPython: How to get sizer from wx.StaticText?

Tags: wxpython, sizer

The widget is in one of many sizers I make, but how to get sizer of one of these widgets, for example in `wx.StaticText`. First, I though wx.StaticText have a method `GetSizer()` because it derived from `wx.Window`, but it always return `None`, is there a way?

Sorry for my poor language.

**EDIT (08/23/2012)** Solution from Mike Driscoll:

Using `self.sizer.GetChildren()` to get `SizerItemList` from some sizer, then using `GetWindow()` to get actual widget from the list

Comment: Could you provide provide a detailed description of what you're trying to do? [GetSizer()](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#GetSizer) will only return a sizer if your previously call `SetSizer()`. Normally, you only call `SetSizer()` on a `wx.Frame` or `wx.Panel`.

Comment: @acattle: Actually, I was trying to get all value from widgets inside sizer, maybe I can use `GetChildren()` from sizer, but it just return **SizerItemList** not actual widget list, so I think I can use `GetSizer()` in all widgets to return the sizer, of course it return nothing.

Sorry, not make myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sizer has children, then GetChildren does return a list of widgets. I've done it many times with wxPython 2.8. I don't remember anyone mentioning it was different in 2.9 or Phoenix, so I'm guessing it's not. Can you tell us which OS and wxPython version you're using?

If you want to know how to get an arbitrary sizer, you might try GetContainingSizer or use the [Widget Inspection Tool](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool)

EDIT (08/22/2012): Here's a working example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyApp(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        lbl = wx.StaticText(panel, label="I'm a label!")
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="blah blah")
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Clear")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClear)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onClear(self, event):
        """"""
        children = self.sizer.GetChildren()

        for child in children:
            widget = child.GetWindow()
            print widget
            if isinstance(widget, wx.TextCtrl):
                widget.Clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Of course the sizer has children, I add them with `Add()`, for example I have two widgets `wx.StaticText` and `wx.TextCtrl`, say I want to clear the `wx.TextCtrl`, I can do this right? `sizer.GetChildren()[1].Clear()`, but error just occur `AttributeError: 'SizerItem' object has no attribute 'Clear'`, maybe I don't understand how `GetChildren()` works. I'm using Windows XP with wxPython 2.8-unicode

Comment: Normally, I just use self.myTextCtrl.SetValue("") or self.myTextCtrl.Clear().

Comment: Looking at this some more, I see that I normally just called the panel's GetChildren(), which does what you want. The sizer appears to work differently and in my opinion, stupidly. One way to keep track of what's in a sizer is to add the items to a list at the same time you add it the sizer and access them that way. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I did like you said, I put all widgets in `OrderedDict()` so I can access them, still confusing me, why panel's `GetChildren()` return the actuall widgets but not for sizer? anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I understand the panel in that it is the "parent" of the "children", but I don't understand why the sizer can't spit out its contents. I'll ask on the wxPython mailing list.

Comment: I added a code example. Cody Precord pointed me in the right direction on the wxPython user's group.

Comment: Brilliant and beautiful! `GetWindow()` really return the actual widget from `SizerItemList`, I've learn many things, thanks to you and Mr. Precord