# wxpython: How do you access the objects which you've placed inside of a wx.Sizer object?

Tags: python, wxpython

During a refactoring session, I put a lot of my gui code into little functions which directly inserts data into a wx.Sizer object.

For instance, this little function:

```
def buildStatusDisplay(self, status_disp, flag):
    grid = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=1, hgap=5, vgap=0)
    font = wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.LIGHT, False, 'Segoe UI')
    for option in status_disp:
        left = wx.StaticText(self, -1, option)
        left.SetFont(font)
        grid.Add(left, 0, flag=flag)
    return grid
```

So it creates all of the StaticText objects using the throwaway `left`, and then returns the `FlexGrid`. However, I need some of the labels in the StaticText objects to update based on user input, but, I'm not sure how to access them.

I've looped through the sizer that gets returned from the function, but I don't see anything relating to a way that would let me get reference to the objects which make up the sizer.

```
for i in dir(sizer):
    print i 

>>Add
>>AddF
>>AddGrowableCol
>>AddGrowableRow
>>AddItem
>>AddMany
>>AddSizer
>>AddSpacer
>>AddStretchSpacer
>>AddWindow
>>CalcMin
>>CalcRowsCols
>>Children
>>ClassName
>>Clear
>>ColWidths
>>Cols
>>ComputeFittingCli
>>ComputeFittingWin
>>ContainingWindow
>>DeleteWindows
>>Destroy
>>Detach
>>Fit
>>FitInside
>>FlexibleDirection
>>GetChildren
>>GetClassName
>>GetColWidths
>>GetCols
>>GetContainingWind
>>GetFlexibleDirect
>>GetHGap
>>GetItem
>>GetItemIndex
>>GetMinSize
>>GetMinSizeTuple
>>GetNonFlexibleGro
>>GetPosition
>>GetPositionTuple
>>GetRowHeights
>>GetRows
>>GetSize
>>GetSizeTuple
>>GetVGap
>>HGap
>>Hide
>>Insert
>>InsertF
>>InsertItem
>>InsertSizer
>>InsertSpacer
>>InsertStretchSpac
>>InsertWindow
>>IsSameAs
>>IsShown
>>Layout
>>MinSize
>>NonFlexibleGrowMo
>>Position
>>Prepend
>>PrependF
>>PrependItem
>>PrependSizer
>>PrependSpacer
>>PrependStretchSpa
>>PrependWindow
>>RecalcSizes
>>Remove
>>RemoveGrowableCol
>>RemoveGrowableRow
>>RemovePos
>>RemoveSizer
>>RemoveWindow
>>Replace
>>RowHeights
>>Rows
>>SetCols
>>SetContainingWind
>>SetDimension
>>SetFlexibleDirect
>>SetHGap
>>SetItemMinSize
>>SetMinSize
>>SetNonFlexibleGro
>>SetRows
>>SetSizeHints
>>SetVGap
>>SetVirtualSizeHin
>>Show
>>ShowItems
>>Size
>>VGap
>>_ReplaceItem
>>_ReplaceSizer
>>_ReplaceWin
>>_SetItemMinSize
>>__class__
>>__del__
>>__delattr__
>>__dict__
>>__doc__
>>__format__
>>__getattribute__
>>__hash__
>>__init__
>>__module__
>>__new__
>>__reduce__
>>__reduce_ex__
>>__repr__
>>__setattr__
>>__sizeof__
>>__str__
>>__subclasshook__
>>__swig_destroy__
>>__weakref__
>>_setOORInfo
```

`GetChildren()` returns only `SizerItems` which don't seem to hold any reference to the underlying objects either.

Anyone know how to access something inside of a sizer? I suppose I could just explode the function a bit and either return a list of the objects as well as the sizer, or simple dump the function and keep identifiers to the objects I need to modify in main.. but... my gui code is already spaghetti enough. If I can avoid it, I would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `wx.SizerItem`, there is a `GetWindow` which gives you exactly that. Use `IsWindow` to check if there is a 'window' available. All underlying objects inherit from `wx.Window`, so that is what you want.

Here is an example, `obj` is a `wx.Frame` object:

```
>>> obj
<main.views.Main; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxFrame *' at 0x7fbaa1c70820> >
>>> obj.Sizer
<wx._core.BoxSizer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxBoxSizer *' at 0x7fba9c9d48d0> >
>>> obj.Sizer.Children
wxSizerItemList: [<wx._core.SizerItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxSizerItem *' at 0x7fbaa1c21630> >, <wx._core.SizerItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxSizerItem *' at 0x7fbaa1c7faf0> >]
>>> obj.Sizer.Children[0]
<wx._core.SizerItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxSizerItem *' at 0x7fbaa1c21630> >
>>> obj.Sizer.Children[0].Window
<wx._windows.Panel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPanel *' at 0x7fba9c9d4d10> >
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I tried both `IsWindow`, as well as `GetWindow`. Both returned AttributeErrors.

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. Thanks for the edit. I was initially calling `Window` on the main sizer, not realizing that I needed to do it on the actual sizer items. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually answered this kind of question a few months ago: [wxPython: How to get sizer from wx.StaticText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031522/wxpython-how-to-get-sizer-from-wx-statictext)

Basically, you just need to do something like this:

```
children = self.sizer.GetChildren()

for child in children:
    widget = child.GetWindow()
    print widget
    if isinstance(widget, wx.TextCtrl):
        widget.Clear()
```

In this case, you can see that I'm just checking for a wx.TextCtrl, but you can check for whatever widget you like. I also wrote an article on the subject on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/24/wxpython-how-to-get-children-widgets-from-a-sizer/).

Answer (score 1):

Probably already referenced in some other places, but could not find it so putting it here...

There is an additional way of doing this by using `name` parameter during child creation i.e.:

```
left = wx.StaticText(self, -1, option, name='StaticTextChild')
```

Child then can be directly referenced/changed without the need for Sizer references.

```
staticTextChild = wx.FindWindowByName('StaticTextChild')
staticTextChild.SetLabel('new label:')
```

This method would probably not work directly in this example as you need to ensure unique child names to be able to access them. How you would do it is up to you.

Comment: wx.FindWindowByName is deprecated. Use wx.Window.FindWindowByName instead. Also, what happens when name is not unique?

Comment: FindWindowByName method will stop as soon as it finds first match and you won't be able to access any possible subsequent matches. At least I'm not aware of such possibility, but I'm not wxpyhton expert...