# Generate List of All sizerItems Nested in wxPython Sizers

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all `sizerItems` which correspond to widgets. To demonstrate, I created the following example:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel 

class Tester(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Window")
        self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1)
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.sizerItems = []

        Btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "I'm a Button!") 
        Btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Me Too!") 
        Btn3 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Hey! Quiet up there!") 
        Btn4 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Jeez Frank, relax") 


        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox1.Add(Btn1, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox1.Add(Btn2, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(Btn3, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(Btn4, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=25)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=25)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()

        self.GetAllChildren(self.panel.GetSizer())
        print self.sizerItems


    def GetAllChildren(self, item):
        try:
            for sizerItem in item.GetChildren():
                self.GetAllChildren(sizerItem)
        except:
            try: 
                item.GetSizer()
                self.GetAllChildren(item.GetSizer())
            except:
                self.sizerItems.append(item)
                return


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
Tester().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This code makes a GUI with 4 buttons.  I want `GetAllChildren()` to return a list (`self.sizerItems`) of all the sizerItems which are not sizers.  For this example, there should be 4 elements in the list corresponding to the four buttons.  `GetAllChildren()` should recursively run down the tree of sizers, so `vbox` first, then `hbox1` and all its children, then `hbox2` and all its children.

Currently though, I get `[None,None,None,None]` as the result. I realize the `try...except` is where it is breaking, but I don't know how else to decide whether a particular item is what I want.  Any suggestions on how to fix this or alternative methods?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with the code a bit and changed it so that it actually returned the widget instances instead of the sizerItem instances:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel 

class Tester(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Window")
        self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1)
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.sizerItems = []

        Btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "I'm a Button!") 
        Btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Me Too!") 
        Btn3 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Hey! Quiet up there!") 
        Btn4 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Jeez Frank, relax") 


        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox1.Add(Btn1, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox1.Add(Btn2, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(Btn3, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(Btn4, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=25)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=25)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()

        self.GetAllChildren(self.panel.GetSizer())
        print self.sizerItems

    def GetAllChildren(self, item):
        for sizerItem in item.GetChildren():
            widget = sizerItem.GetWindow()
            if not widget:
                # then it's probably a sizer
                sizer = sizerItem.GetSizer()
                if isinstance(sizer, wx.Sizer):
                    self.GetAllChildren(sizer)
            else:
                self.sizerItems.append(widget)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    Tester().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can read more about this method in one of my old tutorials:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/24/wxpython-how-to-get-children-widgets-from-a-sizer/

Which, oddly enough, is based on another StackOverflow question:

- [wxPython: How to get sizer from wx.StaticText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031522/wxpython-how-to-get-sizer-from-wx-statictext)

Anyway, when I ran that code above, I got back a list of four buttons. To check and make sure they aren't the same button added 4 times, I did this:

```
for item in self.sizerItems: 
    print item.GetLabel()
```

You might also want to take a look at the Widget Inspection Tool which can visually show you which widgets are in which sizers.

Comment: Brilliant, works great.  I guess I was planning on getting the window once I had the list, but this works just as well. I do have one question though, you have a comment "then its probably a sizer".  Why "probably" and how sure are you that this will be correct?

Comment: In your code, it should always be a sizer. I can't think of anything else that would return a None off the top of my head, but there are some oddball widgets out there that I'm not very familiar with. I suspect it will work in 95% of cases or so though.

Answer (score 1):

the path you are going down leads to the darkside! turn back!

you should just do something like

```
def __init__(self):
     ...
     self.widgets = {
       'text_input':textBox,
       'btn1':btn1,
       ....

     }
```

then just access them later through

```
 my_instance.widgets['text_input'].GetValue()
```

or

```
def validate(self):
      self.widgets['text_input'].GetValue()
```

Comment: Darkside? What's so bad about it?  The "light side" method needs to be updated if I ever change the GUI.  Additionally, ```GetAllChildren``` now only returns an empty list :(

Comment: Yes, but keeping a list can be easier in that it already exists whereas you'll have to generate the other one on demand.

Comment: also you know which textfield or button you are working with ... instead of just knowing its a widget, which you then need to check the type of ... and you need to generate the list every time you want to do anything .... that said Mike answer is excellent(per usual) and answers the question as asked,(even if I disapprove of this method :P) (basically the biggest problem is that the complexity rapidly scales out of control, and the code becomes unmaintainable)